# Send binary file to ttyUSB0 serially in linux

Tags: linux, tty, serial-port, serial-console, ttyusb

I have a binary file(obtained from assembly code). I need to transfer this file to an fpga serially via ttyUSB0.
I read in some posts that using cat and echo data can be transferred to ttyS0.

```
echo -ne '\033[2J' > /dev/ttyS1  
cat  < /dev/ttyS1
```

Does this apply for ttyUSB0 as well? If not, please suggest me other ways to transfer binary file via ttyUSB0.

Answer (score 1):

Serial connections to programmable devices such as microcontrollers or fpgas are often used with tools from the device vendor (or free ones) which handle the communication protocol. Just sending a file down the wire will very rarely work. The development environment of your device should have information on how a compiled binary is programmed into the device.

Comment: My development environment expect binary data. It has a UART receiver implemented to receive data serially.

Comment: So just `cat <your binary> > /dev/ttyUSB0` ... if your FPGA serial is correctly detected and setup by Linux as `/dev/ttySOMETHING`, when it should just behave like a standard serial port.